# Python Microscopy: Framework build using conda on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, frameworks, conda

I am a scientific researcher using a home-written software called Python Microscopy developed by David Baddeley at Yale University (documentation available here http://python-microscopy.org/). I am running the program out of a Python 2.7 conda environment (called `snakes`), on which David Baddeley has his own channel. To perform parts of the image analysis, the program requires the use of `launchworkers.py`, which is described here http://python-microscopy.org/doc/LocalisationAnalysis.html. When I try to run `launchworkers` out of the terminal, I got the following:

```
(snakes) Sabinas-MBP:~ sabinahaque$ launchWorkers
killing ['/anaconda/envs/snakes/bin/python','/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2.
7/site-packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/taskServerZC.py']
killing ['/anaconda/envs/snakes/bin/python','/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2.
7/site-packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/taskWorkerZC.py']
killing ['/anaconda/envs/snakes/bin/python','/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2. 
7/site-packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/taskWorkerZC.py']
killing ['/anaconda/envs/snakes/bin/python','/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2. 
7/site-packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/taskWorkerZC.py']
killing ['/anaconda/envs/snakes/bin/python','/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2. 
7/site-packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/taskWorkerZC.py']
Starting PYME taskServer ...
(snakes) Sabinas-MBP:~ sabinahaque$ /anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PYME/ParallelTasks/fitMonP.py:221: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using 
deprecated class PySimpleApp. 
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

I have done some searching and get the general consensus that changing the path that the environment is running out of will perhaps fix my problem, but I am unsure of how to do this. Does anyone have an idea of how I should go about fixing this? I'm pretty new to Python and StackOverflow so please try to walk me through as much detail as possible!

Comment: [This](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac) should help

Comment: I was unclear about how to change the path...

Comment: Setting the `PYTHONHOME` variable to the virtualenv's location should cause the wx lib to use the proper environment.